# connectiong RESTfull server with Spring MVC via ESB

Tags: rest, esb

I have two servers. First is **RESTfull** server producing XML about goods.
Second is Spring MVC server which should consume XML from first server, proceed it and show it to the client. I need use ESB(servicemix - maybe other) for this task.

So it looks like:

> client => Server2 (Spring) => ESB => Server1 (REST)

and the way back:

> Server1 (REST) => [XML] => ESB => Server2 [processing XML] => [web
>   Page] => client

So I'd like to connect first server to ESB to produce XML. (it seem's to be not so hard task, but still appreciate advice, how to)

But mainly i need to know how to connect second Server (Spring MVC) to ESB and request data from first server? Now I answer clients requests from local DB, but i need to get data from RESTfull server via ESB. I've been searching about it for week with no success.

Could you give me direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a Spring MVC application to a REST service maybe achieved using the Spring 3.x [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access). This would not matter if you talk to the native REST services hosted on Server 1, or proxies you create for those services on the ESB.

You could also refer to the client support of JAX RS frameworks such as Apache [Wink Client](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/1.1.1/html/6.1%20Getting%20Started%20with%20Apache%20Wink%20Client.html) another one [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_client_winkrestclient.html)

An ESB "could" convert the REST services to SOAP etc, but would not suggest that path. To easily create proxy services for REST services, and to convert say - XML to/from JSON etc, you could also consider the [UltraESB](http://adroitlogic.org) which offers very good REST support, and is easy to use and extend [Note - I am the CTO of AdroitLogic developing the UltraESB]